# Extract grid item in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, react-grid-layout

Here is the piece of code from the [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) documentation

```
  var ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
  //...

  render: function() {
  var layout = getOrGenerateLayout(); 
  return (
    <ReactGridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} 
      cols={12} rowHeight={30}>
      <div key={1}>1</div>
    </ReactGridLayout>
  )
}
```

With this I want to extract the *div* element in an React component. So I've added this piece of code :

```
var SimpleDiv = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<div>1</div>);
    }
});
```

And so the first part becomes :

```
  var ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
  //...

  render: function() {
  var layout = getOrGenerateLayout(); 
  return (
    <ReactGridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} 
      cols={12} rowHeight={30}>
      <SimpleDiv key={1}>1</SimpleDiv>
    </ReactGridLayout>
  )
}
```

And the problem is that it's not working, the *div* element is present but no class name transformation occurs.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are wrapping the div element in your custom component so when the `ReactGridLayout` component tries to set properties on its children it'll be setting them on the `SimpleDiv` component. You might be able to make it work by passing along the props like:

```
var SimpleDiv = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<div {...this.props}>1</div>);
    }
});
```

or explicitly:

```
var SimpleDiv = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<div style={this.props.style} className={this.props.className}>1</div>);
    }
});
```

But I'm not too familiar with ReactGridLayout so if that doesn't work you may have to ping them and ask if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an extra 'div' element, you could use:

```
render: function() {
   var layout = getOrGenerateLayout(); 
   return (
      <ReactGridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} 
         cols={12} rowHeight={30}>
         <div key={1}><SimpleDiv>1</SimpleDiv></div>
     </ReactGridLayout>
  )
}
```